# album art grabber python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Im writing a python based app that goes over all the music files and download thier respective album arts.
Im using beautifulsoup4 to scrap the album art from last.fm site.

Is there a better way to go about it? because sometimes i get an exception of too many requests to the site.
Like last.fm api that gives me what i need instead of scrapping.

i found this but i dont think it can be use as i need
https://github.com/pylast/pylast

i have not tried to use it but this is how i do it for now:

```
def getAlbumArt(songDet):
   #create a search url according the name of the given song's album
   try:
       # deletes unnecessary words from the name
        if songDet.albumName.rfind("(") != -1:
            r = requests.get("http://www.last.fm/search?q="+songDet.albumName[:songDet.albumName.rfind("(")])
        else:
            r = requests.get("http://www.last.fm/search?q=" + songDet.albumName)
        html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        imagesLinks = html.find_all("ol")
        r.close()
        for imageLink in imagesLinks:
            for image in imageLink.contents:
                if type(image) is bs4.Tag:
                    if image.text.__contains__(songDet.artist):
                        # todo add path to save pic to the mp3 path
                        urllib.urlretrieve(image.find("img").attrs['src'], image.find("img").attrs[u'alt'] + ".jpg")
                        print "got a picture"
                        return True
                        #break
            #break
   except requests.RequestException as e:
       print e
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this? if so, can you provide a code sample of what you have?

Comment: i have not tried to use it but this is how i do it for now http://pastebin.ca/3583239

Comment: Hey @Liran, next time make sure you add the code into your question. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely start using the `last.fm` API.

And, to avoid "too many requests" issue, if you are not using the API, [be a good web-scraping citizen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91760/how-to-be-a-good-citizen-when-crawling-web-sites) and introduce delays between your requests - you can start with something as simple as `time.sleep(delay_in_seconds)` (you would need to `import time` of course).